# Destructuring promise callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

There is a promise in my code:

```
req.getValidationResult()
        .then(result => {
            let errors = result.array();
            if (errors.length) {
                return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors });
            }
            
            return next();
        });
```

I'd like to know is there any variants to destructure my 'result' variable on then call (something like `.then({result.array(): errors} =>...`) and not to make `let errors = result.array();` assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's impossible with the native promise. You can change this code a bit:

```
req.getValidationResult()
        .then(({array}) => array())
        .then(errors => {
            if (errors.length) {
                return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors });
            }
            return next();
        });
```

Or you can use bluebird. It has a `call` method:

```
req.getValidationResult()
        .call('array')
        .then(errors => {
            if (errors.length) {
                return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors });
            }
            return next();
        });
```

But in the case you need to cast your promise to Bluebird promise